# Converting a struct to a hex string in C

Tags: c

I have the following struct

```
typedef struct __attribute__((packed)) word {
    uint16_t value;
    uint8_t flag
} Word;
```

I want to convert it to a hex string. For example if `value = 0xabcd` and `flag = 0x01` I want to get the string `01abcd`

if I do some pointer juggling

```
Word word;
word.value = 0xabcd;
wordk.flag = 0x01;

printf("word: %X\n", *(int *)&word);
```

I get the output that I want (`word: 1ABCD`) but this doesn't seem safe
and when I tried to do this after looking at some of the answer here

```
char ptr[3];
memcpy(ptr, word, 3);
printf("word: %02X%02X%02X\n", ptr[2], ptr[1], ptr[0]);
```

I got `word: 01FFFFFFABFFFFFFCD`, for some reason the first two bytes are being extended to a full int

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to get the string 01abcd

So you want to print the binary representation of the struct on a little endian machine backwards. There's no obvious advantage of using `sprintf` for this apart from it being quick & dirty to implement.

If you want something with performance, then hacking this out manually isn't rocket science - simply iterate over the struct byte by byte and convert each nibble to the corresponding hex character:

```
void stringify (const uint8_t* data, size_t size, char* dst)
{
  for(size_t i=0; i<size; i++)
  {
    uint8_t byte = data[size-i-1]; // read starting from the end of the data
    dst[i*2]   = "0123456789ABCDEF"[ byte >> 4  ]; // ms nibble
    dst[i*2+1] = "0123456789ABCDEF"[ byte & 0xF ]; // ls nibble
  }
  dst[size*2] = '\0';
}
```

This will give `"01ABCD"` on a little endian machine and `"01CDAB"` on a big endian machine.

(Optionally add `restrict` to `data` and `dst` parameters but I doubt it will improve performance since the const correctness already blocks aliasing at some extent.)

Answer (score 3):

There's no real gain from messing around with pointers or type-punning, if all you want is to output the values of the two structure members. Just print them individually:

```c
printf("word: %02x%04x\n", (unsigned int)word.flag, (unsigned int)word.value);
```

Comment: `%x` expects an `unsigned int` parameter so you should add casts ro avoid UB

Comment: @AdrianMole: No, they will not. `uint8_t` will be promoted to `int`. `uint16_t` will be promoted to or already is `unsigned int` if that is 16 bits. Otherwise, it will be promoted to `int`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Oops. excellent point ... edited. (Those integer promotion rules can still bite me!)

Comment: The gain from "messing around with pointers" would be massively improved execution speed, much smaller binary size and no `stdio.h` format string/va arg/non-existent type safety hazards present in the program (as illustrated by the above comments). How exactly is faster, smaller and safer "no real gain"?

Answer (score 2):

Use a simple sprintf to convert to a string:

```
int main(void)
{
    Word v = { 0xabcd, 0x01 };
    
    char s[10];
    
    sprintf(s, "%02x%04x", v.flag, v.value);
    
    puts(s);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could join them mathematically first.

```
printf("word: %06lx\n", wordk.flag * 0x10000L + word.value);
```

Using `long` in case we are on a 16-bit `int` machine.